# intersect 4 lists in python with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, numpy, intersect

Is there a way to do with list comprehension the following:
I have 4 lists: t1, x1(t1), t2, x2(t2). t1 and t2 have different length, and so do x1 and x2. I want to add up the values of x1 and x2 in which t1 and t2 intersect and for those values where t2 and t1 don't intersect just append their values in two new lists x and t.

```
t1 = [0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 80.0]
x1 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
t2 = [40.0, 50.0, 80.0]
x2 = [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

so that my new t and x are:

```
t = [0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 80.0]
x = [1.0, 2.0, 10.0, 12.0, 5.0, 15.0]
```

This is the code with a double loop. Although so far it only does the add up. Still need to append those values for both t1, t2, x1 and x2 that do not intersect:

```
x = [] 
t = []
for y in range(len(t1)):
    for z in range(len(t2)):
        if t1[y] == t2[z]:
           t.append(t1[y])
           x.append(x1[y] + x2[z])
```

Comment: why not working with `set()` of values instead of lists

Comment: Post the working-but-slow code. Your sample input/output are really unclear and personally I'm not able to figure out how your algorithm is supposed to work at all from them

Comment: Yes because 10, 15 and 12 are the sum of the x1 and x2 where t1 and t2 intersect

Comment: it's better with the code !

Comment: This is a very weird kind of _intersect_ ...

Comment: Your `t` list is just `t1`. Should it be `t = list(set(t1)-set(t1).intersection(t2))`?

Comment: Yes of course, that's why I said I still needed to append those values for t1, t1, x1, x2 that do not intersect. But I'm not sure how...

Comment: Will t1 always contain more values, or in other words, only t2 will contain the duplicates?

Comment: That's the problem, sometimes t1 is larger than t2 but in most occasions the length of t2 is larger than for t1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `heapq.merge` to "zip" together the timings and then `itertools.groupby` to find the coincidences. These are all linear complexity operations, so this should scale well:

```
import heapq, itertools, operator
t, x = zip(*((k, sum(map(operator.itemgetter(1), v))) for k, v in itertools.groupby(heapq.merge(zip(t1, x1), zip(t2, x2)), operator.itemgetter(0))))
t
# (0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 80.0)
x
# (1.0, 2.0, 10.0, 12.0, 5.0, 15.0)
```

Step-by-step:

```
merged = heapq.merge(zip(t1, x1), zip(t2, x2))
# make list for printing
merged = list(merged)
merged
# [(0.0, 1.0), (20.0, 2.0), (40.0, 3.0), (40.0, 7.0), (50.0, 4.0), (50.0, 8.0), (60.0, 5.0), (80.0, 6.0), (80.0, 9.0)]
grouped = itertools.groupby(merged, operator.itemgetter(0))
# make printable
grouped = [(k, list(v)) for k, v in grouped]
grouped
# [(0.0, [(0.0, 1.0)]), (20.0, [(20.0, 2.0)]), (40.0, [(40.0, 3.0), (40.0, 7.0)]), (50.0, [(50.0, 4.0), (50.0, 8.0)]), (60.0, [(60.0, 5.0)]), (80.0, [(80.0, 6.0), (80.0, 9.0)])]
t, x = zip(*((k, sum(map(operator.itemgetter(1), v))) for k, v in grouped))
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have 4 lists: t1, x1(t1), t2, x2(t2). t1 and t2 have different
>   length, and so do x1 and x2. I want to add up the values of x1 and x2
>   in which t1 and t2 intersect and for those values where t2 and t1
>   don't intersect just append their values in two new lists x and t.

```
t1 = [0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 80.0]
x1 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
t2 = [40.0, 50.0, 80.0]
x2 = [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

First thing, create dictionaries for the data you have "key" and "value" pairs, instead of trying to mangle a common index around:

```
data1 = dict(zip(t1, x1))
data2 = dict(zip(t2, x2))
```

Now, just create a dictionary out of these two, by combining their keys:

```
data3 = {key: data1.get(key, 0) + data2.get(key, 0)  for key in set(list(data1.keys()) + list(data2.keys()))}
```

And there is your data.
If you will really need then as lists:

```
t = data3.keys()
x = data3.values()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! I got this error when trying your idea. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set'

Comment: Sorry for that I will never figure why don't they use `+` for union. Should be working now.

Comment: You should not rely on the order of `keys` and `values`; better do `t, x = zip(*sorted(data3.items()))`

Comment: @jsbueno That would lead to awkward things like `(a+b)-b != a` if `a` and `b` share any elements.

Answer (score 1):

So far this works for summing the values of x1 and x2 if their corresponding t values match:

```
t2 = [0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 80.0]
x2 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
t1 = [40.0, 50.0, 80.0]
x1 = [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]

t = [i for i in t1 for j in t2 if i==j]
x = [sum(i) for i in [(x1[i], x2[j]) for i, k in enumerate(t1) for j, l in enumerate(t2) if t1[i]==t2[j]]]
print(t)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
t = [40.0, 50.0, 80.0]
x = [10.0, 12.0, 15.0]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! That's nicer than my double for loop, however I still need to append the values where nothing was added. Any ideas for that are really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
t1 = [0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 80.0]
x1 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
t2 = [40.0, 50.0, 80.0]
x2 = [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]

t_product = list(itertools.product(t1,t2))
intersec_indexes = [(t1.index(x),t2.index(y)) for x,y in t_product if x==y]
longer_x = x1 if len(x1)>len(x2) else x2

result_x = []
for index, i in enumerate(longer_x):
    index_x1 = intersec_indexes[0][0]
    index_x2 = intersec_indexes[0][1] 
    if index == index_x1:
        result_x.append(x1[index_x1] + x2[index_x2])
        intersec_indexes.pop(0)
    else:
        result_x.append(x1[index])

result_t = []
result_t = list(set(t1+t2))
result_t.sort()

print(result_t)
print(result_x)
```

Result:

```
[0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 80.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 10.0, 12.0, 5.0, 15.0]
```